# match and check if 2 values are equal or not

Tags: powershell

I have 2 variables were I am getting value like below

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>> $todhome.tod_disk_type
STANDARD
STANDARD
STANDARD
```

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>> $todhome.actual_disk_type
STANDARD
STANDARD
STANDARD
```

Please let me know how to match and check they are same or not

tried below but not working

```
if ($todhome.tod_disk_type -match $todhome.actual_disk_type)
```

output for compare-object

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $a
STANDARD
STANDARD
STANDARD

PS C:\Windows\system32> $b
STANDARD
STANDARD
STANDARD

PS C:\Windows\system32> Compare-Object $a $b

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: What is the output of `$todhome | gm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Compare-Object` to compare two sequences:

```
# define two string arrays with the same values
$a = -split 'STANDARD STANDARD STANDARD'
$b = -split 'STANDARD STANDARD STANDARD'

# Use Compare-Object to find any differences
$diff = Compare-Object $a $b

if($diff){
  # differences were found 
}
```

Comment: Still the `$diff` is giving blank value. both `$a` and `$b` are same.

Comment: @EmptyCoder Correct, that's expected - if they're different, `Compare-Object` would have output something :)

Comment: Nothing. it is giving blank. if it is different at least it should give False. please correct me if I am wrong/

Comment: added the output in question

Comment: @EmptyCoder The fact that the output is blank simply means the two sequences were considered equal :) It's working as expected

Comment: but `$diff` is going to else part because of that. I have to right `OK` if true else `False`

Comment: Then `$same = -not $diff` and return `$same` instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239497/discussion-between-empty-coder-and-mathias-r-jessen).

Comment: @EmptyCoder `Compare-Object` by default is looking for **differences**. If there are no differences, that means the two variables are the same and Compare-Object will have no output. So, `if (Compare-Object $a $b) { '$a is NOT equal to $b' } else { '$a is equal to $b' }`

Comment: Note that by default `Compare-Object` matches input array elements even if out of order. So `1, 2, 3` compares equal to `2, 3, 1`. Pass `-SyncWindow 0` if order is important.